# Get all files in a matching subdirectory name

Tags: python-3.x, os.path, pathlib

I have this piece of code from another project:

```
import pathlib
p = pathlib.Path(root)
for img_file in p.rglob("*.jpg"):
    #Do something for each image file
```

It finds all jpg files in the whole directory and its subfolders and acts upon them.

I have a directory that contains 100+ 'main' folders with each folder having some combination of 2 subfolders - lets call them 'FolderA' and 'FolderB'. The main folders can have one, both or none of these subfolders.

I want to run a piece of code against all the pdf files contained within the 'FolderB' subdirectories, but ignore all files in the main folders and 'FolderA' folders.

Can someone help me manipulate the above code to allow me to continue?

Many thanks!

Comment: Can you demonstrate *any* effort at solving this yourself?

Comment: I sure can:
I've found the libraries relative to my issue. I've found a piece of code that gets me a good bit towards the answer (see above). I have stated the part which i am struggling on (only returning files which match a desired folder). I searched google and stackoverflow with various ways of asking the question (my issue is i'm a novice and often don't know the name of concepts i am looking for).
Perhaps you can direct me towards a concept which I could read into and find the answer for myself?

Comment: Have you looked at the values you are getting back from `p.rglob`?

Comment: The values returned appear to be every file matching the ".jpg" at the end of the path string. But how do i try to specify a piece of text, ie. "FolderB" that occurs in the _middle_ of a path and then subsequently return those files? The placeholder string "FolderB" i have used in this case can be in the name of a file contained within "FolderA". So previous attempts to just change ".jpg" to "FolderB" have returned a number of incorrect files. (sorry the asterisks seem to have messed up the formatting of the comment! i have one before the .jpg and before and after the FolderB) @ScottHunter

Comment: If the values contain each file's path, you can tell which folder each is in, and act accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

You can modify the pattern to just search for what you want:

```py
from pathlib import Path

p = Path("root")
for file in p.rglob("*FolderB/*.pdf"):
    # Do something with file
    pass
```